# Combo box binding in mvvm

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, silverlight, mvvm

I am not able to find out Why is combo box binding not working?

I have a view model which looks like (2 properties)

```
    public ProcessMaintenanceDataObject CurrentProcess
    {
        get
        {
            return _CurrentProcess;
        }
        set
        {
            _CurrentProcess = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("CurrentProcess");
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<ProcessMaintenanceDataObject > Processes 
    {
        get
        {
            return _Processes;
        }
        set
        {
            _Processes = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Processes");
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<FolderInfo> Folders
    {
        get
        {
            return _folders;
        }
        set
        {
            _folders = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Folders");
        }
    }
```

The following is the ProcessMaintenanceDataObject definition

```
    [DataMember]
    public string ProcessName
    {
        get
        {
            return _ProcessName;
        }
        set
        {
            _ProcessName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ProcessName");
        }

    }


    [DataMember]
    public string Id
    {
        get
        {
            return _Id;
        }
        set
        {
            _Id = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Id");
        }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string FolderId
    {
        get
        {
            return _FolderId;
        }
        set
        {
            _FolderId = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("FolderId");
        }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public FolderInfo Folder
    {
        get
        {
            return _Folder;
        }
        set
        {
            _Folder = value;
            if (_Folder != null)
                FolderId = _Folder.FolderId;
            OnPropertyChanged("Folder");
        }
    }
```

The FolderInfo class has FolderName and FolderId Property.

I have a method in viewmodel which fills the Processes.
In my view I have structure something like, I have a  treeview which will be bound to Processes and while selecting any of the item from the treeview, i need to allow user to edit that entity.

In the view the combo box binding is as:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Folders, Mode=OneWay}"
          DisplayMemberPath="FolderName" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding  Source={StaticResource viewModel}, Path=CurrentProcess.Folder, Mode=TwoWay}">
...
```

This binding doesn't work I mean when I select any object from the tree it fills other information like ProcesName in the textBox but it doesn't make the Folder object as the selected item in combobox, however the combo box will be filled.

Any suggestion.

Do refer this:
[image]

Comment: What is `FolderCollection`?

Comment: FolderCollection is an ObservableCollection of FolderInfo. FolderInfo is a class with two properties FolderName and FolderId.

Comment: can u also paste the method   which fills the Processes ?

Comment: ` private void RefreshProcessess()
        {
            Client.GetProcessesCompleted += (sndr, args) => 
            {
                try
                {
                    Processes = args.Result;
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                                       
                }
            };
            Client.GetProcessesAsync();            
        }`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to bind a ComboBox to your folders property in two way mode with edit support,
Then you should define data template for your combo box and then bind properties of FolderInfo class to those text boxes
Binding display member path will not solve your problem

Comment: I have bound ComboBox's ItemsSource to Folders. I don't want to disturb Folder Collection I mean I dont want to edit the FolderInfo.

Comment: I've not looked at your view model , It's not important
Within [Display Member Path] only, you will not  be able to modify any thing from ComboBox , It will only shows data to you , without any mechanism to change the data that is bounded.

Comment: If you have any error, then put the error message here, but if you've tried @anatollig's sample, and your combo box is remained read only, then you've no problem, there is no need to stack panel at that sample, and you should use text box instead of text area,.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to change `DisplayMemberPath` with appropriate `DataTemplate`:

```
<DataTemplate>
  <StackPanel>
     <TextBlock Text="{Binding FolderName}">
  </StackPanel>
<DataTemplate>
```

This will fix `SelectedItem` context.

Comment: It is also not working
I changed the Combo Box as:
 `<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Folders, Mode=OneWay}" SelectedItem="{Binding  Source={StaticResource viewModel}, Path=CurrentProcess.Folder, Mode=TwoWay}">
                <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding FolderName}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ComboBox>`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just maybe, your Folderinfo class is not a notificationObject. If it is the case make sure it implements INotifyPropertyChange.

Comment: It implements INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use SelectedValuePath and SelectedValue instead of SelectedItem like below,

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Folders, Mode=OneWay}"
          DisplayMemberPath="FolderName"
          SelectedValuePath="FolderId" 
          SelectedValue="{Binding Path=FolderId, Mode=TwoWay}">
```

SelectedItem binds the whole object whereas SelectedValue binds only particular properties of the object.